# Install devkit for pik-installed Rubies

Tags: ruby, windows, devkit, pik

I've installed two rubies using pik, but I haven't installed any rubies outside of pik.

When I choose a Ruby using pik, and then try to set up devkit, no binaries are added to the generated config.yml file:

```
# This configuration file contains the absolute path locations of all
# installed Rubies to be enhanced to work with the DevKit. This config
# file is generated by the 'ruby dk.rb init' step and may be modified
# before running the 'ruby dk.rb install' step. To include any installed
# Rubies that were not automagically discovered, simply add a line below
# the triple hyphens with the absolute path to the Ruby root directory.
#
# Example:
#
# ---
# - C:/ruby19trunk
# - C:/ruby192dev
#
---
```

I tried adding the binaries within pik to the path, so that config.yml has

```
- C:/pik/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136
- C:/Users/agrimm/.pik/rubies/JRuby-170preview1
```

but I get

```
bash-3.1$ ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] Updating convenience notice gem override for 'C:/pik/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136'
[INFO] Installing 'C:/pik/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/devkit.rb'
[ERROR] Unable to find RubyGems in site_ruby or core Ruby. Please
install RubyGems and rerun 'ruby dk.rb install'.

C:\DevKit>ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] Skipping existing gem override for 'C:/pik/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136'
[WARN] Skipping existing DevKit helper library for 'C:/pik/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136'
[ERROR] Unable to find RubyGems in site_ruby or core Ruby. Please
install RubyGems and rerun 'ruby dk.rb install'.

C:\DevKit>gem --version
1.3.7

C:\DevKit>echo %PATH%
C:\pik\rubies\ruby-1.9.2-p136\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Parallels Tools\Applications;C:\pik\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\DevKit\bin

C:\DevKit>PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\agrimm\.pik\rubies\JRuby-170preview1\bin

C:\DevKit>echo %PATH%
C:\pik\rubies\ruby-1.9.2-p136\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Parallels Tools\Applications;C:\pik\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\DevKit\bin;C
:\Users\agrimm\.pik\rubies\JRuby-170preview1\bin

C:\DevKit>ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] Skipping existing gem override for 'C:/pik/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136'
[WARN] Skipping existing DevKit helper library for 'C:/pik/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136'
[ERROR] Unable to find RubyGems in site_ruby or core Ruby. Please
install RubyGems and rerun 'ruby dk.rb install'.
```

Do I need to install a ruby outside of pik in order to have devkit work?

Answer (score 2):

I see that this question is old, but still unanswered. Your post mentions that you installed the ruby versions using pik. I don't know what pik does under the covers when installing ruby, but I've always used the Rubyinstallers directly. They have worked fine with pik, and I've installed DevKit with no problem. Note this bit from the [DevKit docs](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit):

> *ruby dk.rb init* to generate the config.yml file to be used later in this Step. Your installed Rubies will be listed there (only those installed by a RubyInstaller package are detected at present).

Comment: Why the downvote? It directly answers the question posed by the OP at the end of the post, and it's how I got pik and devkit to play well together. See the help page on downvoting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)